# What are the specifics of S.H.I.E.L.D. becoming H.Y.D.R.A.?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shield, hydra

We learn in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* that S.H.I.E.L.D. was actually a front for H.Y.D.R.A.. However, the original members of S.H.I.E.L.D. probably didn't intend for it to become H.Y.D.R.A.. Was one of the original founding members of S.H.I.E.L.D. responsible for S.H.I.E.L.D. becoming H.Y.D.R.A.? Was S.H.I.E.L.D. always just a front for H.Y.D.R.A.? Or did it happen along the way, and if it did, when did it happen and who is responsible for it?

Comment: Agents of SHIELD season 5 suggests that plans were in motion some 28 years ago as Hale was sent in as a sleeper agent. I don't quite recall if there is any specific HYDRA interference with the SSR in Agent Carter, but I imagine there would have been, which puts it back to the 1940's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem started when the precursor to S.H.I.E.L.D., the [Strategic Scientific Reserve](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Strategic_Scientific_Reserve), recruited several leading Hydra researchers, including [Arnim Zola](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Arnim_Zola), after World War II.

Unbeknownst to the SSR -- and to S.H.I.E.L.D. when it was later founded, with the former SSR being folded into it -- Zola remained loyal to Hydra, and acted as a mole within both the SSR and S.H.I.E.L.D.. He was apparently able to use his influence to aid the recruitment of more like-minded individuals, allowing to the number of Hydra members within S.H.I.E.L.D. to grow over the years, to the point where they were on the brink of taking full control of S.H.I.E.L.D. in 2014, the year in which *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* was set.

> ARNIM ZOLA UPDATE
>
> FIRST APPEARANCE: *Captain America: The First Avenger (2011)*
>
> Following World War II, Dr. Arnim Zola was imprisoned by the Strategic Scientific Reserve for his involvement with the Nazi science division Hydra. He met Johann Fennhoff in prison and expressed interest in Fennhoff's work on matters of the human mind. **Sometime later, Zola was recruited to work for the new peacekeeping organization S.H.I.E.L.D. in exchange for amnesty. His S.H.I.E.L.D. handlers remained unaware that Zola also continued to secretly work for Hydra.**
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Guidebook to the Marvel Cinematic Universe - Captain America: The Winter Soldier](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Guidebook_to_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_-_Captain_America:_The_Winter_Soldier)*</sub>

> HYDRA UPDATE
>
> FIRST APPEARANCE: *Captain America: The First Avengers (2011)*
>
> **After the Strategic Scientific Reserve defeated Nazi rogue science division Hydra in 1945, the United States recruited several leading Hydra researchers -- including the Red Skull's top scientist, Arnim Zola -- granting them amnesty for SSR service. But as the SSR grew into S.H.I.E.L.D., Hydra secretly festered within as like-minded agents were recruited.**
>
> [...]
>
> **By the modern day, Hydra had infiltrated every echelon of S.H.I.E.L.D., and counted several top operatives among the peacekeeping organization's members -- including Brock Rumlow, Jasper Sitwell, and one of its leaders, World Security Council Secretary Alexander Pierce.**
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Guidebook to the Marvel Cinematic Universe - Captain America: The Winter Soldier*</sub>

> **Zola's scientific mind makes him a top S.H.I.E.L.D. recruit. However, he uses his position to rebuild Hydra.**
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Marvel Studios: Character Encyclopedia](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Studios:_Character_Encyclopedia)*</sub>